# Assign event to custom drawn shape

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, gdi

How do I *draw* a line and assign events to it? I would like to draw a custom shape, but it should act like a normal Control, and have properties and events. E.g.:

```
button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawLine(width, height, location, location, color, panelToDrawShapeOn, nameThisShape);
}

nameThisShape_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Click event raised.");
}

private void DrawLine(int width, int height, int location, int location, Color color, Panel panel, string controlName)
{
    // Code to draw shape and setup events for it.
}
```

To confirm, I do know how to draw shapes using GDI+ but the problem is, they are static, and I can't "interact" with them, and no amount of searching has led me to the right place to find out how to interact with the shapes that I draw.

Comment: The direct solution would be to actually use Controls. If you want a more lightweight solution, you will have to do a lot of additional work especially in the planning; these 'virtual controls' or 'draw objects' will have to share their parent's Graphics; you will have to find a way to hit test a list of them, care for z-order, etc.. possible, but no small feat..

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to treat custom-drawn shapes as you would controls.  As you've found, GDI+ is an [immediate mode graphics system (as opposed a retained mode system)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This means that if you want a persistent scene graph full of shapes to be rendered, you need to create and manage that yourself.  Then, you would hook the events of interest on the control that's the drawing target and handle them by doing hit tests on your list of renderable objects (e.g., to find what shape, if any, the mouse is over).

Writing that code can be a lot of work, but you can find libraries to help you.  For instance, in one of my work projects, we used a computational geometry library called [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) for the geometry representation and hit test code.  If you want to avoid third-party libraries, you may get part of the way there with the [Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.aspx) class, which will at least give you hit tests.

Comment: In addition to `Region` it may help to look at `GraphicsPath.`